# Keep the checkbox result same even page is refreshed

Tags: javascript

The out put of this code is shown by an image.How can I keep the same results even after page refresh. In other word, when once a button click how can I remain the same result even page is refreshed?

```
<style>
    #cb3.highlight .label {background-color:yellow;}
        #cb2.highlight .label {background-color:green;}
        #cb1.highlight .label  {background-color:red;}
    </style>
    <script>
    var checked = [];

        $(document).ready(function() {
            if (localStorage.getItem("checked") == null)
                localStorage.setItem("checked", checked);

            $("#Table input").click(function() {
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    $(this).parent().parent().addClass("highlight");
                    checked.push($(this).attr("id"));
                } else {
                    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("highlight");
                    checked.remove($(this).attr("id"));
                }
                localStorage.setItem("checked", JSON.stringify(checked));
            });

            var saved = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("checked"));
            for (var i = 0;i < saved.length; i++) {
                var itemAtIndex = $("#" + saved[i] + "");
                itemAtIndex.click();
                itemAtIndex.parent().parent().addClass("highlight");
            }
        });
    </script>
    <div class="col-lg-10">

    <table id="Table" border="1">
          <tr id="cb1">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb1" value="y" /></td>
            <td class=label>Click me</td>
        </tr><tr id="cb2">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb2" value="y" /></td>
            <td class=label>Click me</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="cb3">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb3" value="y" /></td>
            <td class=label>Click me</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

***output***
[image]

Comment: try out [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: You will have to store the state of the checkbox somewhere. A database would be a good choice if you want this selection to be saved **always**. However, as [was mentioned by prasad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45353292/keep-the-checkbox-result-same-even-page-is-refreshed#comment77667876_45353292), localstorage is an option if you want to store some data locally on the users machine and it would not break your application if the data was to be deleted.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? I have no idea

Comment: If you can you should ask the person who implemented this code, since it's already using `localStorage` to persist the state of the checkboxes

Comment: Actually he has already tried to implement this feature : that's the `for` block at the end of the `$(document).ready` callback. You will probably want to edit your question to "why doesn't this implementation work", but it would really be best if you looked deeper into it first

Comment: Alright so I got curious, here are two bugs I found : 1) when first initialized, the "checked" value set isn't stringified, which causes bugs everywhere. You will want to `localStorage.removeItem("checked")` at first to clear that incorrect value (neither `null` nor an `array`, but the empty string). 2) the code tries to store the `id` of the checkboxes, but they have no id, so all it's storing in the array is `null`. Maybe you don't want to ask the implementer after all ;)